# Setting up a counter on daily basis

Tags: php, mysql

For our recent project we need to include a counter based on date.

For example a page view counter for answer.php is set in mysql table called `counter`.

Daily access to `answer.php` is limited to 150(page views). the table `counter` will store each access and when daily allowance 150 is over then it gives a warning that you exceeded your limit and block the display.

But I am not able to figure out how this can be done on daily basis. I mean when the next day starts how the counter can be reset and start from 0.

Answer (score 2):

The curdate function returns the current date, so something similar to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) from logintable where 'logindate' = CURDATE()";
```

I realise your query would probably involve more tables and fields. This is a very simplistic off the top of my head untested reply, I'm not sure it even works. Just thinking out loud here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @stefgosselin was the first thing you'd want to do; then if the count was < 150, insert a row.  If the count was 150 or more, reject the query and tell them they had reached their threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Is it 150 pages per user??? or total no matter who.  If its per user, then it should be as simple as adding a single counter to that user's record and keep increasing each time a countable "request" comes in, and look at that count as needed to prevent results as restricted.

Then, since a user has no way of back-dating his/her requests, at the beginning of each day (even via some trigger), you can just update your table to reset all counts back to zero...

Update UserLoginTable set RequestCount = 0

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You create a table called loginlog (a log of all the logins)

```
table loginlog
  id integer autoincrement primary key
  user_id integer
  logindate date
  logincount integer
```

unique key `userdate`(user_id, logindate)

Next you create a before update trigger on your table

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER bu_loginlog_each BEFORE UPDATE ON loginlog FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  /*Force an error by selecting from a non-existing table*/
  /*this will prevent the update*/
  IF new.logincount > 150 THEN SELECT * FROM create_error_only_150_logins_allowed
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

In your php code do the following:

```
INSERT INTO loginlog (user_id, logindate, logincount) 
  VALUES ('$user_id',curdate(),1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE logincount = logincount + 1
```

Test if the insert succeeded.
If the insert/update fails your user has logged in > 150 times and you can refuse the user.

This will only keep one record per user per day. You can even purge past days from the loginlog table after x number of days.

Answer (score -1):

You need a table which maps dates to pageviews

Comment: You don't need such table. You just need to save the last date.

Comment: Sure, but you'll end up writing something in the db. So you can also keep the data for statistical purposes

Comment: Then you'd better keep max, avg, whatever you need and remove the individual visit histories from the table. Imagine a site with 1000 pages with 1M daily views. Such a history table fills up the space soon!

Comment: I don't think so. How did you get your figures?

Comment: He doesn't need to store page views for *ALL days*, instead he only needs the views for *today* so he can do his limiting. Now let's do a rough calculation. Let's think an integer is stored as 4 bytes in DB (without overhead and stuff), and site has 1000 pages: each day will occupy 4 KiB on the DB, in a year it'd be ~1.4 MiB, and so on... even none of the data is going to be used later. (*1M daily views* in my previous comment was a mistake, nothing to do with this). Therefore he'd better store accumulated data rather than each single day or visit. Btw I was not the downvoter.

Comment: @Hossein it's not about the downvote. It's an old answer I reviewed by chance. 1.4MB per year (per user as I understand) is very little IMHO, because you have to consider how much data a user can insert in the DB in the same time frame. Also, for 150 you don't even need 4 bytes. Just speculating here :D

Comment: OK I'm just explaining. Space becomes critical if you want to run a small website since most cheap hosting plans don't have much disk space. In addition, as I said the data is not going to be used again so why keep it? Database engines may use different systems of saving numbers, which could take even more than 4 bytes.

Comment: @Hossein MySQL's `TINYINT` unsigned ranges 0-255 and [is only 1 byte](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html#integer-types). Nowadays storage is cheap. If you run a cheap hosting service, you have so few users that 1 byte/day per user doesn't matter. Keeping data is useful for statistical purposes. You don't have to keep the data for all the days in the last ten years, but you could simply build a service which periodically computes aggregates of oldest data - but I remark, 1 byte/user/day is really little compared to, let's say, a 140 characters tweet